# Is PowerShell Push-Location Thead-Safe

Tags: powershell

Is it safe to use `Push-Location`/`Pop-Location` inside a `ForEach-Object -Parallel` block?

I have an existing script in which I am pushing to, and popping from, the location stack. I now want to invoke this script with different arguments inside a parallel `ForEach-Object`, but am not sure if this is thread-safe. Is there a separate location stack for each runspace, or will each parallel thread be trying to push/pop the same stack?

Comment: It should be according to [Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/push-location?view=powershell-7.3#notes)